# pytest: How to define mandatory command line arguments

Tags: python, pytest

How can I define custom command line arguments, and make them mandatory in pytest?

For example, I want something like this:

```bash
pytest -s sample.py --test_suite='some_value'
```

And the command line argument `--test_suite` has to be mandatory. If it's missing, I want to throw a "help" message like, "enter the test_suite to be executed".

This is my code:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def testsuite(request):
    test_suite = request.config.getoption('--test_suite')
    return test_suite

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--test_suite",action="store",default="default_suite",
                     help="Enter the test suite you want to execute."
                          "Ex. --test_suite=default_suite"
                          "If nothing is selected, default_suite tests will be run.")
```

This approach makes the command line arguments optional. But I want to make them mandatory.

Comment: Does adding `required=True` to the test_suite option work?

Comment: yes! It does! thank you so much :)

Comment: @MikeGillett Can you add your comment as an answer so that Namratha can accept it?

Answer (score 6):

To mark a command line argument as mandatory using `addoption`, add `required=True` as a keyword argument to the method call